# jq - select an object based on existence of a property

Tags: json, jq

At first glance this sounds like its incredibly straight forward but I've been at it for hours.

I am trying to extract the name of the parameter object (which cannot be known), but only if it has a "defaultValue" key listed.

Input object (Azure ARM template):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "componentName": {
            "defaultValue": "storage",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetId": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The subnet to which this storage component belongs."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {}
}
```

Desired output:

```
    "componentName": {
        "defaultValue": "storage",
        "type": "string"
    }
```

I have tried many iterations of the following to no success:

```
.parameters[] | select(  has( "defaultValue"))
```

(expands the object beyond its name of "componentName" - though this does correctly find the matching object of the two)

```
.parameters | map(select(has("defaultValue")))
```

(same deal as above)

```
.parameters | select( any (has( "defaultValue")))
```

(this incorrectly returns the SubnetId object as well, which does not have the "defaultValue" property)

Clearly I am misunderstanding something fundamental. I would greatly appreciate any advice or direction that could be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output is not a valid JSON. The closest I know to get (without custom string formatting) is:

```
jq '.parameters | map_values(select(has("defaultValue")))'
# => {
#      "componentName": {
#        "defaultValue": "storage",
#        "type": "string"
#      }
#    }
```